# ruby string comparisons .match vs .eql?

Tags: ruby

When I used .match and .eql? for string comparison they gave different results

```
text_from_page = "wrong length (should be 64 characters)"
error_text = "wrong length (should be 64 characters)" 
if(text_from_page.eql? error_text)
 puts 'matched' 
else
  puts 'Not matched'
end
```

The following comparison did not work

```
if(text_from_page.match error_text)
 puts 'matched' 
else
  puts 'Not matched'
end
```

Does anyone know the reason for this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As always, don't just use methods without reading their documentation. There can be important notes.

Here's [`eql?`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/String.html#method-i-eql-3F):

> Two strings are equal if they have the same length and content.

Here's [`match`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/String.html#method-i-match):

> Converts pattern to a Regexp (if it isn’t already one), then invokes its match method on str. If the second parameter is present, it specifies the position in the string to begin the search.

Note the part about *converting*. In a regular expression `(` and `)`, among other characters, have significant meaning. You can't use `match` arbitrarily here. It has a very specific function.

You rarely see `.eql?` used in actual Ruby code, the convention is simply this:

```
text_from_page == error_text
```

The `eql?` method is primarily intended for internal use. It comes into play when doing comparisons, and when finding things in a container like an Array or Hash.

Answer (score 0):

@tadman. Thank you. That solved my issue. The ".match" compares the hash values where as the ".eql" compares the stings.